# Failing to use transactions in Quill to INSERT one-to-many relational objects

Tags: mysql, sql, scala, quill.io

I have a person table and animal table and in the animal table there is FK to personId since there is one-to-many relation between them.

I just want to create a person and create its animals using a transaction cause I want the process to be atomic (there is no use of person in the db if I could not create its animals)

This is the model of how I accept a person creation request:

```
case class PersonCreateRequest(name: String, age: Int, animals: Seq[AnimalCreateRequest])
```

This is how the DB knows a Person:

```
case class Person(personId: Long, name, age: Int)

// this is just a companion object to help me take a PersonCreateRequest and make it Person
object Person {
  def apply(person: PersonCreateRequest): Person = {
    Person(0L,
           person.name,
           person.age)
  }
}
```

same thing I have with Animal:

```
case class AnimalCreateRequest(animalType: String, age: Int)
```

This is how the db knows a Animal(personId = owner):

```
case class Animal(animalId: Long, animalType: String, age: Int, personId: Long)

// here I need to get personId as parameter cause I will only have it after a person was created:
object Animal {
  def apply(animal: AnimalCreateRequest, personId: Long): Animal = {
    Animal(0L,
           animal.animalType,
           animal.age,
           personId)
  }
}
```

**So now this is how I tried to do it(and failed):**

```
lazy val ctx = new MysqlAsyncContext(CamelCase, "ctx")
  import ctx._


  def insertPerson(personToCreate: PersonCreateRequest): Future[Long] = {

    // getting the person object that the db knows
    val dbPerson = Person.apply(personToCreate)

    // INSERT Person Query
    val insertPersonQuery = quote {
      query[Person].insert(lift(dbPerson)).returning(_.personId)
    }

    ctx.transaction { implicit ec =>
      for {
        personId   <- ctx.run(insertPersonQuery)
        contactIds <- {
          Future.sequence(
          personToCreate.animals.map(animal => {
            val animalToInsert = Animal.apply(animal, personId)
            insertAnimal(animalToInsert)
          })
          )
        }
      } yield personId
    }
  }

  def insertAnimal(animal: Animal): Future[Long] = {
    val q = quote {
      query[Animal].insert(lift(animal)).returning(_.animalId)
    }
    ctx.run(q)
  }
```

What happens is that I just dont get a response...its keep processing without returning anything or throwing an error

Comment: Please add more information about the error you get.

Comment: @mixel What happens is that I just dont get a response...(added to the question) is it the way you suppose to handle this task anyway? i am new to this library

Answer (score 2):

Problem was, currently, Quill async does not support concurrent operations inside transactions.

So had to do the animal insertion sequentially:

```
ctx.transaction { implicit ec =>
  for {
    personId <- ctx.run(insertPersonQuery)
    animals = personCreate.animals.map(Animal.apply(personId, _))
    _ <- animals.foldLeft(Future.successful(0l)) {
      case (fut, animal) =>
        fut.flatMap(_ => insertAnimal(animal))
    }
  } yield personId
}
```

also, even better is to use batch insertion :)

Thanks for @fwbrasil and @mentegy for the assistance!

Answer (score 0):

Add implicit `ExecutionContext` parameter to `insertAnimal` method:

```
def insertAnimal(animal: Animal)(implicit ec: ExecutionContext): Future[Long] =
```

Without it, you're not passing ec from the transaction block and animal insertions will try and use other connections from the pool.

Comment: why do i need that if I import `import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.{global => ec}
`, it  dosent let me have both :/

Comment: If you want to execute queries in transaction, they must use that ec you implicitly get after invoking transaction method. If `insertAnimal` uses global ec, then those inserts are run outside of transaction.

Answer (score 0):

Are you familiar with [Scala Futures](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/futures.html)?

To get a result from a transaction you should add `onSuccess` handler to a `Future` returned from the `ctx.transaction` call:

```
ctx.transaction { ...
}.onSuccess {
  case personId => ...
}
```

Comment: why? I want to return a future to the controller

Comment: Ok, then return it and handle in the controller. You wrote "it keeps processing without returning anything or throwing an error". What do you mean by that then?

Comment: in my controller I have this: `peopleDao. insertPerson(personToCreate).map { personId =>
          Ok(s"personId: $personId")` this should work and I just dont get an answer...i honestly trying to figure out what is happening still :/

Comment: You should add minimal but complete example reproducing your issue. It may be issue with your http server library configuration or something else. Could your create example project on GitHub?